# Получить список удаленных файлов в git начиная с определенного коммита

Tags: git

Список измененных файлов начиная с определенного коммита это

```
git diff --stat --name-only 123abc
```

или

```
git log --no-renames --name-only --format='' 123abc..HEAD
```

В эти списки попадают как новые, измененные, так и удаленные файлы.

Хочется список удаленных файлов получить отдельно.

Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 5):

Вроде так:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter D <commithash> HEAD
```

с логом так же, добавить флаг `--diff-filter D`, типа

```
git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D | sort -u
```